# Unknown Type Error in C

Tags: c, while-loop, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have to create a program in C that allows the user to enter and degree and number. I'm learning C right now and its hard to tell if I'm doing it right.I'm not sure why I get these unknown type name. I'm suppose to use a switch statement, while loop, and the converter functions.

```
/* Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter */
#include <stdio.h>      /* definitions of printf, scanf */
#include <math.h>       /* definitions of sqrt, pow */
#define FCR 0.556       /* defines the value for FCR */
#define CFR 1.8         /* defines the value for CFR */
double fc_converter(double);
double cf_converter(double);
int
main(void)
{
        double fahrenheit;
        double celsius;
        char degrees;

    printf("Hello > Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter. Please enter F or C:");
    scanf("%c", &degrees);
    while (degrees == 'F' || 'f' || 'c' || 'C' )
    {
            switch(degrees){
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                    printf("Hello > Please enter a Fahrenheit degree number:");
                    scanf("%lf", &fahrenheit);
                    return(fc_converter(fahrenheit));
                    break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                    printf("Hello > Please enter a Celsius degree number:");
                    scanf("%lf", &celsius);
                    return(cf_converter(celsius));
                    break;
            default:        
                    printf("The input is unknown!");
                    break;
                    }
            break;
    }

}
double fc_converter(double, fahrenheit)
{

    if (fahrenheit >= -200) && (fahrenheit <= 200)
    {
            celsius = FCR * (fahrenheit - 32.00);
            printf("The calculated value from the converter function is:%.2f", fahrenheit);
            return celsius;
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Invalid Celsius temperature.");
            return (celsius = sqrt(fahrenheit));
    }

}
double cf_converter(double, celsius)
{
    if(celsius >= - 200) && (celsius <= 200)
    {
        fahrenheit = CFR * celsius + 32.00;
        printf("The calculated value from the converter function is:%.2f", celsius);
            return fahrenheit;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Fahrenheit temperature.");
        return(fahrenheit = pow(celsius, 3));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
HW3.c:44:22: error: unknown type name ‘fahrenheit’
HW3.c:61:22: error: unknown type name ‘celsius’
```

Comment: `(double, fahrenheit)` -> `(double fahrenheit)`

Comment: Read your code at the lines the error occurs. For instance, `ouble fc_converter(double, fahrenheit)` - what is the compiler supposed to think `fahrenheit` is in that declaration.

Comment: @JETM After I took that out it gave me an error HW3_fip.c: In function ‘fc_converter’:
HW3_fip.c:46:29: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
HW3_fip.c: In function ‘cf_converter’:
HW3_fip.c:61:26: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token

Comment: The error column should identify where this is happening. The `if` is only evaluating `( fahrenheit >= -200 )` in the first case. In other words, `if( boolean_expression )` - where your boolean_expression is '( fahrenheit >= -200 ) && ( fahrenheit <= 200)', you want all that in `( )`. `if( ( fahrenheit >= -200 ) && ( fahrenheit <= 200) )`. On a side note it's interesting that range does not include the boiling point of water.

Comment: Also, can you see why your while loop condition will 'constant'ly evaluate to 'true' (nonzero) and why it will only ever iterate one time. Also, the return value of `main ()` is `int`... P.S. there are more runtime issues

Answer (score 0):

Addressing only the syntax errors:

```
double fc_converter(double, fahrenheit)
```

Should be:

```
double fc_converter(double fahrenheit)
```

The other error is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature is incorrect. You are having a comma between the argument type and the argument name. A comma is used to separate arguments in method signature.

`double fc_converter(double, fahrenheit)`

should be

`double fc_converter(double fahrenheit)`

AND

`double cf_converter(double, celsius)`

should be

`double cf_converter(double celsius)`